# Resources, where to put them, and how to reference them in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I've worked with C# and other programming languages for a while now, and am ashamed to say I'm unfamiliar with the standard on where to put resources such as program icons, and how to reference them within my code.

Specifically, for a C# Windows Forms Application, where would it be appropriate to put my icon resources, and what is the path for referencing them once I get them in the correct place?

Thanks very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add a **Resources.resx** file to your project and add resources like images, strings, files to it. Then you can reference these resources through an automatically-generated `Resources` class. By default, Visual Studio will create a **Resources.resx** file in the **Properties** directory. Any resources you add to the resources file will be added to the **Resources** directory by default.

e.g.

```
this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.MyImage;
```

Comment: You have an idea on how to reference it in Visual Studio with the GUI once it is places in the Resources.resx file? All of the code is generated automatically and uneditable. :(

Comment: Ah, I just referenced the location that the icon is automatically placed when you add it to the resources.resx file in the file system. I'm hoping that will still be the correct location when I create a release for this app.

Comment: If you add a file to Resources.resx, it will be included in your assembly as an embedded resource. It does not need to be included as a separately file when you release your application.

Answer (score 18):

For completion I wanted to expound on some of the answers listed.

### Embed in Resources.resx

`Resources.resx` should have been created when your WinForms project was created.  You can view it under `Properties` in the `Solution Explorer`.

[image]

Double click `Resources.resx` to open the designer.  You can copy from `Windows Explorer` and paste in the VS resources designer.  This tool is smart enough to figure out what type of resource it is, and you can see in the screen shot below that similar resource types are grouped together under the menu bar's drop down list.

[image]

From this point you can follow the accepted answer and manually assign the resource to a control's property...

> this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.MyImage;

---

### Embed in form via designer

Using the designer, you can embed a resource in a form's `.resx`.
Select the control in the designer and open the `Properties` window (`F4` is default shortcut key).  Find the appropraite property, such as `Icon` for a form.  Click the ellipses button to bring up the `Open File` dialog.  Browse to the resource (if you embedded it in the `Resources.resx` it will actually be in the `Resources` folder - which would have been created when you added your first resource to `Resources.resx` - and you should use the first method above), and select the correct resource.

In the image below you can see the "scrape.ico" file being set as the `Main` form's `Icon`.

[image]

This example would end up generating a line in the `Main` form's designer like this...

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

where...

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Main));
```

and in `main.resx`...

```
<data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
        ...img data...
    </value>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always do it this way.

Go to Project-->Project properties(always name of project + properties)-->Resources

On the upper menu bar you will find a combo box where you will select which type of element you want to use as a resource.

Example: If you need to change the icon for the form(the one that appears an the upper left side of the form) you will then to upload a ".ico" file. If you need to insert a button image you must upload a ".png" file. You can see this [Resx files tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEfST1-9oFk) youtube video where it's explained perfectly

Once you have done this you select the control you wish to insert the image in and go to Properties-->Image and the select the image you have just added from Project Resource file option.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the Code to Fetch Image From Resources Folder. Normally we keep images in Resources Folder. but Sometime we have image name only with us. in that case you can Access images from Resources Folder using Image Name only.

Below Code will Demonstrate about it.

```
private System.Resources.ResourceManager RM = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("YourApplicationNameSpace.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);

PictureBox1.Image = (Image)RM.GetObject(YourPictureName);
```

- **YourAppliacationNameSpace** means name of your Application.
- **YourPictureName** means the Picture you Want to access from Resources Folder. but Picture name must be without Extension e.g. (PNG, GIF, JPEG etc)

hope it will be beneficial to some one.

Thank you.