# Preventing SlowCheetah from encoding "<", ">" and adding &#xD;&#xA; for carriage returns

Tags: .net, app-config, slowcheetah

I am using SlowCheetah for transforming my application config file. My problem is that some of the values that it replaces are SQL statements that have conditions like `... where x > 1` and the `>` ends up being encoded as `&gt;`,  `\r\n` ends up as `&#xD;&#xA;` and so forth. If I send this sort of statement to the database will throw an error.

How do I prevent this? I googled already with no luck.

Comment: Don't you tell slow cheetah what to tranform?  Why are you transforming off those keys?

Comment: @BillBlankenship No, I am not telling SlowCheetah to transform those keys but SlowCheetah still goes through everything. For example, if you have a setting in your config file like so: `<add key="foo" value="bar" />` SlowCheetah will still transforms it to `<add key="foo" value="bar"/>` (removes last space). What's annoying is that is modifying stuff you don't even tell it to modify and in the process, encoding stuff that will break things.

Comment: Hmmm, I haven't experienced that before.  In my experience it only transformed the keys that I told it to transform.  I wonder if there is some sort of comment or tag to inform slow cheetah to leave this segment alone and not encode.

Comment: it's not transforming line-by-line, it loads entire document, transforming it parts and then saves entire document back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "fix" this issue - if you can call it that - I ended up moving the section that contained the special characters that were being encoded by SlowCheetah to a different file, and set the `configSource` attribute in the section to point to the new file. Basically, I did this:

```
<pluginsSection configSource="Configs\pluginsConfig.xml"> 
</pluginSection>
```

Now SlowCheetah transforms the `App.config` file and the contents of `pluginsConfig.xml` are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

These symbols are forbidden symbols in XML. Slow Cheetah is using XmlTransformableDocument, which I think inherits from XmlDocument, thus when transformation applied - all non-XML-markup symbols are being  encoded, including your ">" signs.

I don't think you can easily fix this behaviour, and not sure why you're using transformations on non-valid XML document.

Comment: It also encodes text inside quotes, which is a pain. I've scrapped slowCheetah on my project for now, e.g. the >0 is being encoded:     <target name="fileAsException"  
            xsi:type="FilteringWrapper" 
            condition="length('${exception}')>0">
      <target xsi:type="File"  
              fileName="${LogFileName}"  
              layout="${ExceptionVerboseLayout}" />
    </target>

Answer (score 0):

**in general:** placing your sql statements inside a config file (or any unprotected file in that matter) is not such a brilliant idea.. if anyone would ever put their hands on that gile file they will gain priceless information about your database structure and logic.

please consider use **stored procedures** that hides database logic, names, operators and such (your config will just contain stored procedures calls with parameters - without forbbiden xml chars)

if you still insist to place your sql queries as a plain text - that is why .net has **resources**... instead of placing those statement inside your condig file, put them inside your project resources (a file with a resx extension)

*for winforms applications*: [Resources, where to put them, and how to reference them in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111160/resources-where-to-put-them-and-how-to-reference-them-in-c-sharp)

*for web applications*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

*for libraries (dll files)*: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5447/NET-Localization-using-Resource-file

Comment: Using stored procs is not always possible in this case. The SQL statements are to be executed on different database systems (Sybase, MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, Excel files, etc.) Access to all databases is read-only and from views that do not expose any sort of sensible information; moreover, this is an internal application. As far as using resources and so forth, it's a bit of a hassle to set that up considering the way the program is designed, which consists of a bunch of plugins each of which has its own config section within the App.config. Thanks for your answer.