# How to read a txt file and edit it from project resources

Tags: c#, winforms

I need my code to read data from a txt file and write it to a variable from the project resources, please help

```
var exePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var path = Path.Combine(exePath, "Base\\base.txt");

string contents = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: This code works, but how do I read the txt file from the project resources and not from the path on the computer

Comment: Do you mean a resx file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111160/resources-where-to-put-them-and-how-to-reference-them-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, but the compiler throws an error, does not see this file (base.txt )

Comment: If you're getting a file's contents from a Resx file, you don't access it by _path_ (or with File.Read...). See the above link. It's exactly the same as strings in a resx file.

Comment: You should edit your original post and include the code you are using to try to read the resource file and the specific error you are getting so the community can better assist you.

Comment: I still don't understand how to read files with resx can you help me give an example of code with reading a txt file