# Placing strings shared by two or more projects in a referenced project in a solution

Tags: c#

I currently have two projects in a solution that share similar classes. In order to resolve the sharing issue of the classes I have created a third project in the solution and both the projects reference those classes. Now I have come to a point where both the projects would need to share common strings. Now I wanted to add those string to the common solution but I am not sure how to approach this. Should I simply create a class and have those strings declared as static with getters and setters ? Any suggestions

Comment: you can use static class...

Comment: This question can help: [common resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065/referencing-resource-files-from-multiple-projects-in-a-solution) ?

Comment: Are those configuration strings like connection string or path to a file etc, or are they just constants that you simply want to share? If latter, Darins solution is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use constants:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string Message1 = "Foo bar";
    public const string Message2 = "Baz";
}
```

and then call those constants in the consuming code:

```
string text = Constants.Message1;
```

Alternatively you might consider using resource files. The advantage of resource files is that they could be localized in various languages if you need to support multi language application.